# What does this syntax mean in Swift?

Tags: swift, function

I am new to Swift and am confused with this type of syntax. I know when you add () to the end of something you initialize it. I am still confused what this means though! I am adding code below.

Please help clarify what parenthesis at the end of this means! Thank you!

Also what does it mean to have all that code after the equal sign in this case? ( I know how to create a variable and add a String,Int or something like that to it).

I am just confused a bit wth this code.

Thanks for being understanding to a beginner!

```
 var viewController: ViewController = {

return self.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Play") as ViewController

}()
```

EDIT 1 -

```
var statusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle = .Default {

        didSet{

            setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()    
     }

}
```

Comment: `{ ... }` defines a closure (a function-like object), and `()` runs it. `viewController` is initialized with the result of the `return` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{}` declares a closure, which is anonymous function. Everything between `{` and `}` is a function body. Since closure defined in provided code does not have arguments it can be executed as regular function by `()`. `{ .. }()` is just defining and immediately executing of anonymous function.

In a body of a function there is a call of `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Play")` which returns `AnyObject`. As `viewController` *variable* (`var`) expected to ba a type of `ViewController`, we cast `AnyObject` result of `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` `as` `ViewController`

As for `statusBarStyle`, UIStatusBarStyle is an enum. `.Default` is one of enum's cases. It can be written alternatively as `var statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.Default`. The code that goes in the `{ ... }` is a way to declare getter and setter behavior. In this particular case there is only one behavior `didSet` defined, which means as soon as value of `UIStatusBarStyle` updated (which is possible, as it is `var`), call function `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`. There are other getters & setters keywords that you may read about in Swift Book — https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329 such as `get`, `set`, `willSet`.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I finally see what it means. I added something to the code above. Can you please explain it also?!

Comment: Also From your answer the () at the end is what make the closure be executed?

Comment: @SteveSmith `()` is something that makes any function to be executed that takes zero arguments as input. Closure is a function that does not have a name aka anonymous function.

Comment: @SteveSmith I updated my answer with an explanation regarding `didSet`. Good luck with your learning :)

Answer (score 3):

As Nikita said its instantly calling the anonymous function you declared. This is really useful as it allows you to add logic when initialising a `var` or `let`.

Since the function takes no arguments, it makes it harder to see at first that it actually is a function. An example with an argument makes this concept a lot clearer.

```
let oneMore: Int = { (num: Int) in num + 1 }(5) //oneMore = 6
```

We are creating a function that takes one `Int` argument `num` and implicitly returns an `Int` (the compiler knows this because of the type annotation on `oneMore`. By following the closure with `(5)` we are calling the anonymous function with the value of `5`.

Hopefully this example makes it more clear what happening. Note for an anonymous function in the context we would never need to provide argument since it will only ever be called once with the arguments following it, so we can just include the argument within the function body.

```
let oneMore: Int = { 5 + 1 }()
```

---

In the second example the braces are allowing you to include property observers to the variable. an example of a property observer is `didSet` which is called each time **after** you assign a value to the variable. more info can be found in apples docs [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

Comment: @This was also a great answer! Thanks for clarifying everything.